# JSON populating incorrectly in an array

Tags: c#, jquery, arrays, json

I have getting the following JSON:

```
[
{
    "name":"Bob",
    "gender":"Male",
    "age":23,
    "pets":
    [
        {
            "name":"Garfield",
            "type":"Cat"
        },
        {
            "name":"Fido",
            "type":"Dog"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name":"Jennifer",
    "gender":"Female",
    "age":18,
    "pets":
    [
        {
            "name":"Garfield",
            "type":"Cat"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name":"Steve",
    "gender":"Male",
    "age":45,
    "pets":null
},
{
    "name":"Fred",
    "gender":"Male",
    "age":40,
    "pets":
    [
        {
            "name":"Tom",
            "type":"Cat"
        },
        {
            "name":"Max",
            "type":"Cat"
        },
        {
            "name":"Sam",
            "type":"Dog"
        },
        {   
            "name":"Jim",
            "type":"Cat"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name":"Samantha",
    "gender":"Female",
    "age":40,
    "pets":
    [
        {
            "name":"Tabby",
            "type":"Cat"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name":"Alice",
    "gender":"Female",
    "age":64,
    "pets":
    [
        {
            "name":"Simba",
            "type":"Cat"
        },
        {
            "name":"Nemo",
            "type":"Fish"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

When i filling the array it only prints out the first object `Bob` not the others.The code to print out is:

Owner.cshtml

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $.get("@Url.Action("GetOwnerDetailsAsJson", "Home")",
                function (response) {

                    var $male = $('#male');


                    for (var i = 0; i <= response.length; i++)
                    {
                        $male.append('<li> ' + 'Name: ' + response[i].Name + ' Pets: ' + response[i].Pets[i].Name + ' <li>');
                    }

                });


        });
    });
```

OwnerController:

```
public Array GetOwnerDetailsFromJson()
    {
        var url = "http://www.igeniusgroup.com/people.json";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        string json;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            json = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Owner[] ownersArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Owner[]>(json); 
        return ownersArray;
```

HomeController:

```
public JsonResult GetOwnerDetailsAsJson()
    {
        OwnerController ownerCont = new OwnerController();

        return Json(ownerCont.GetOwnerDetailsFromJson(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I'm going wrong somewhere however can't tell where. Help please

Comment: What happens when you debug it? What value does `response.length` have?

Comment: It's 6 which is correct.

Comment: It's probably crashing here: `response[i].Pets[i].Name`. You're assuming the ith person has i+1 pets. Also, your condition should be `i < response.length`

Comment: Yes, it is crashing there for sure because the names are printing out correctly. i+1pets because some owners have more than one pets unless i have taken a wrong approach.

Comment: Well yes, but you'd have to loop through each pet. You'd have two loops here. Some people may have 0 pets, some people may have 15. The number of pets they have doesn't depend on what index the person is at. Inside your loop you'd have another `for (var j = 0; j < response[i].pets.length; j++) { //etc }`

Comment: And based on @Rob code it would be simpler if you sent empty array instead of `null` when user doesn't have pets

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) 
                        {
                            for (var j = 0; j < response[i].pets.length; j++)
                            {
                                $male.append('<li> ' + ' Pets: ' + Pets[i].Name + ' <li>');
                            }
                        }` you mean like this? @Rob

Comment: It's not working with that approach Rob

Comment: Just worked. I was using the wrong variable in the second loop